# Intuition Behind Xavier Initialization

Tags: statistics, variance

Can anyone explain why to compromise between the variances 1/n_in and 1/n_out its 2/(n_in+n_out) its not an average or a harmonic mean it seems random to me?[image]

The full paper is here:https://proceedings.mlr.press/v9/glorot10a.html

Comment: $\frac{2}{n_i+n_{i+1}}$ *is* the harmonic mean of $\frac{1}{n_{i}}$ and $\frac{1}{n_{i+1}}$: it is the reciprocal of the mean of $n_i$ and $n_{i+1}$

Comment: @Henry how is it a harmonic mean woudnt harmonic mean be $$2/(1/n_i +1/n_{i+1})$$

Comment: $2/(1/n_i +1/n_{i+1})$ is the harmonic mean of $n_i$ and $n_{i+1}$ while $2/(n_i +n_{i+1})$ is the harmonic mean of $1/n_i$ and $1/n_{i+1}$.  Here the variances are $1/n_{i}$ and $1/n_{i+1}$ or perhaps  $1/n_{\text{in}}$ and $1/n_{\text{out}}$

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but when doing a harmonic mean would you not leave $1/n_{in}$ and $1/n_{out}$ in the form that they are because harmonic mean is used to bring things to the same scale and since both are 1/  a diffrent number you use common denominator to be able to add them ?

Comment: The harmonic mean of $x$ and $y$ is $\dfrac{2}{\frac1x+\frac1y}$.  If $x=1/n_i$ and $y=1/n_{i+1}$ then this is   $\dfrac{2}{\frac1{1/n_i}+\frac1{1/n_{i+1}}} = \dfrac{2}{n_i+{n_{i+1}}}$.  The reason for doing it is largely unrelated to how you do it, though it is sensible to have $x$ and $y$ having the same sign.

Comment: So by taking the Harmonic mean as opposed to the arithmetic mean it allows for their to be a much more rapid decrease in the variance as the discrepancy of between the size of the layers or n_in and n_out changes which I guess the researches found to work better for neural networks